# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken called on 'Allow Access'

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I expected `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` to be called once on app startup in response to push notification registration.

But, I noticed that it's called 2 times: once when the push notification registration succeeds, and the **other time when the user taps on 'Allow Access'**! The latter is not expected given the documentation.

Push notification registration code:

```
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
              UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

- It happens only in iOS 10. I tried running it on iOS 9 and it doesn't happen there.
- I made sure that `registerForRemoteNotifications` is not called more than once.

A few observations (as expected):

1. When I call just `registerForRemoteNotifications` and NOT `registerUserNotificationSettings`, then `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` is called just once.
2. When I call just `registerUserNotificationSettings` and NOT `registerForRemoteNotifications`, then `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` isn't called at all.

Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Why does it matter?  You should be prepared for `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` to be called at any time and update your backend with the token when it is.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am using push notifications for communication between webserver and mobile app. So, during mobile app startup, I need to make sure that push notifications are successfully registered. If this code gets executed twice, I end up executing some setup logic twice (like a lock gets released twice).

Comment: You should change your logic then; You should call `registerForRemoteNotifications` each time your app starts, which will result in a call to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`.  In most case you will receive the same token, but you may receive a different token if the device has been restored from backup or iOS has been re-installed.  It is incorrect to assume that `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` will only be called once per-app per-install

Comment: @Paulw11 I understand that `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` can be called more than once. That's why I have been trying to come up with a way where a successful push registration notifies my code just once during initialization, and not thereafter. 

The other question is: Is it expected that didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken be called when user presses 'Allow Access' for push notifications?

Comment: Maybe.  Certainly that is what you are observing.  That is why I suggest that your code shouldn't care if it gets multiple remote notification registrations for the same app launch on a single device.  Attempting to unlock an unlocked lock just results in an unlocked lock.

Answer (score 0):

For That You need To call Method registerForRemoteNotifications in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:

```
   // Method For ReGister Notification 

func registerUserNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
        guard granted else { return }
        self.getNotificationSettings()
    }
}

 // Method For seeting if User Don;t allow For Remote Notification

  func getNotificationSettings() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        })
    }
}
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
           // Override point for customization after application launch.
    registerUserNotifications()

    return true
}
```

Comment: I am using silent push notifications in my app for webserver communication. I can't afford to not call registerForRemoteNotifications().